# Symfony 6 - JWTRefreshTokenBundle - "Gesdinet\JWTRefreshTokenBundle\Entity\RefreshToken" is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle, symfony6

I am installing JWTRefreshTokenBundle on a Symfony 6 and PHP 8.1 base

I followed the documentation and I get the following error:
Class "AppEntityRefreshToken" sub class of "Gesdinet\JWTRefreshTokenBundleEntityRefreshToken" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

I continued to search and tried the following procedure:
https://github.com/markitosgv/JWTRefreshTokenBundle/issues/332

But the result is the same.

What is strange is that in the documentation we have to update our database with the new RefreshToken entity and absolutely nothing happens even when forcing the update

You will find below the different files.

If someone has an idea, I'm interested ! Thanks in advance

-- App\Entity\RefreshToken.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gesdinet\JWTRefreshTokenBundle\Entity\RefreshToken as BaseRefreshToken;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table("refresh_tokens")
 */
class RefreshToken extends BaseRefreshToken
{
}
```

-- security.yaml

```
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false        
    api:
        pattern: ^/api/
        stateless: true
        entry_point: jwt
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/authentication_token
            provider: app_user_provider                
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure  
        jwt: ~
        refresh_jwt:
            check_path: /api/authentication_refresh    
            provider: app_user_provider                
    main:
        jwt: ~
```

-- routes.yaml

```
json_login:
    path: /api/authentication_token

refresh_token:
    path: /api/authentication_refresh
```

-- gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token.yaml

```
gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token:
    refresh_token_class: App\Entity\RefreshToken
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found a way to solve your issue.
You need to delete your App/Entity/RefreshToken file then you use the Symphony CLI and run

```
symfony console make:entity // or php bin/console ...
```

Name the entity RefreshToken and don't add any property

Then delete the repository class that has just been made and go inside the file App/Entity/RefreshToken to make it look like that :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Gesdinet\JWTRefreshTokenBundle\Entity\RefreshToken as BaseRefreshToken;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: "refresh_tokens")]
class RefreshToken extends BaseRefreshToken
{

}
```

You can now

```
symfony console make:migration
```

then

```
symfony console d:m:m
```

It should work like a charm when you ping your login route

EDIT:

Your security.yaml firewalls should look like that:

```
firewalls:

        dev:
            pattern: ^/_(profiler|wdt)
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:  ^/login
            stateless: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            json_login:
                provider: app_user_provider
                check_path: /login
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            logout:
                path: /logout
            
    
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            jwt: 
                provider: app_user_provider
                authenticator: lexik_jwt_authentication.security.jwt_authenticator
        
        api_token_refresh:
            pattern: ^/token/refresh
            stateless: true
            refresh_jwt: ~
```